# Fourier coefficients for NFFT - non uniform fast Fourier transform?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, fft

I am trying to use the package pynfft in python 2.7 to do the non-uniform fast Fourier transform (nfft). I have learnt python for only two months, so I have some difficulties.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from pynfft.nfft import NFFT

#loading data, 104 lines
t_diff, x_diff = np.loadtxt('data/analysis/amplitudes.dat', unpack = True)

N = [13,8]
M = 52

#fourier coefficients
f_hat = np.fft.fft(x_diff)/(2*M)

#instantiation
plan = NFFT(N,M)

#precomputation
x = t_diff
plan.x = x
plan.precompute()

# vector of non uniform samples
f = x_diff[0:M]

#execution
plan.f = f
plan.f_hat = f_hat
f = plan.trafo()
```

I am basically following the instructions I found in the pynfft tutorial (http://pythonhosted.org/pyNFFT/tutorial.html).

I need the nfft because the time intervals in which my data are taken are not constant (I mean, the first measure is taken at t, the second after dt, the third after dt+dt' with dt' different from dt and so on).

The pynfft package wants the vector of the fourier coefficients ("f_hat") before execution, so I calculated it using numpy.fft, but I am not sure this procedure is correct. Is there another way to do it (maybe with the nfft)?

I would like also to calculate the frquencies; I know that with numpy.fft there is a command: is ther anything like that also for pynfft? I did not find anything in the tutorial.

Thank you for any advice you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, taken from [here](https://github.com/ghisvail/pyNFFT/issues/26):

First we define the function we want to reconstruct, which is the sum of four harmonics:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

%pylab inline --no-import-all

# function we want to reconstruct
k=[1,5,10,30] # modulating coefficients
def myf(x,k): 
    return sum(np.sin(x*k0*(2*np.pi)) for k0 in k)

x=np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,1000)   # 'continuous' time/spatial domain; -0.5<x<+0.5
y=myf(x,k)                     # 'true' underlying trigonometric function

fig=plt.figure(1,(20,5))
ax =fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y,'red')
ax.plot(x,y,'r.')

                        # we should sample at a rate of >2*~max(k)
M=256                   # number of nodes
N=128                   # number of Fourier coefficients

nodes =np.random.rand(M)-0.5 # non-uniform oversampling
values=myf(nodes,k)     # nodes&values will be used below to reconstruct 
                        # original function using the Solver

ax.plot(nodes,values,'bo')

ax.set_xlim(-0.5,+0.5)
```

The we initialize and run the Solver:

```
from pynfft import NFFT, Solver

f     = np.empty(M,     dtype=np.complex128)
f_hat = np.empty([N,N], dtype=np.complex128)

this_nfft = NFFT(N=[N,N], M=M)
this_nfft.x = np.array([[node_i,0.] for node_i in nodes])
this_nfft.precompute()

this_nfft.f = f
ret2=this_nfft.adjoint()

print this_nfft.M  # number of nodes, complex typed
print this_nfft.N  # number of Fourier coefficients, complex typed
#print this_nfft.x # nodes in [-0.5, 0.5), float typed


this_solver = Solver(this_nfft)
this_solver.y = values          # '''right hand side, samples.'''

#this_solver.f_hat_iter = f_hat # assign arbitrary initial solution guess, default is 0

this_solver.before_loop()       # initialize solver internals

while not np.all(this_solver.r_iter < 1e-2):
this_solver.loop_one_step()
```

Finally, we display the frequencies:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(1,(20,5))
ax =fig.add_subplot(111)


foo=[ np.abs( this_solver.f_hat_iter[i][0])**2 for i in range(len(this_solver.f_hat_iter) ) ]

ax.plot(np.abs(np.arange(-N/2,+N/2,1)),foo)
```

cheers